# Vaadin Grid + Dialog: Как обновить таблицу после выхода из диалога?

Tags: java, grid, vaadin, dialog

Я использую Vaadin 14. У меня есть Grid, в котором выводятся пользователи, и кнопка добавления пользователя, которая открывает диалог для такого добавления.

```
@UIScope
@Route
@SpringComponent
@Slf4j
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final AddUserDialog addUserDialog;
    private Grid<UserDto> grid;

    public MainView(UserService userService,
                    AddUserDialog addUserDialog) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.addUserDialog = addUserDialog;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void renderComponents() {
        renderHeader();
        renderAddUserButton();
        renderUserGrid();
    }

    private void renderAddUserButton() {
        Button addUserButton = new Button("Добавить", VaadinIcon.PLUS.create());
        addUserButton.addClickListener(event -> addUserDialog.open());
        add(addUserButton);
    }

    private void renderUserGrid() {
        grid = new Grid<>(UserDto.class);

        grid.setItems(userService.getAll());

        Grid.Column<UserDto> id = grid.getColumnByKey("id");
        Grid.Column<UserDto> username = grid.getColumnByKey("username");
        Grid.Column<UserDto> password = grid.getColumnByKey("password");
        Grid.Column<UserDto> email = grid.getColumnByKey("email");
        Grid.Column<UserDto> phone = grid.getColumnByKey("phone");
        Grid.Column<UserDto> active = grid.getColumnByKey("active");

        List<GridSortOrder<UserDto>> sortOrders =new ArrayList<>();
        GridSortOrder<UserDto> order = new GridSortOrder<>(id, SortDirection.DESCENDING);
        sortOrders.add(order);
        grid.sort(sortOrders);

        id.setHeader("ID");
        username.setHeader("Имя пользователя");
        password.setHeader("Пароль");
        email.setHeader("email");
        phone.setHeader("Телефон");
        active.setHeader("Активен");

        List<Grid.Column<UserDto>> columns = Lists.newArrayList(id, username, password, email, phone, active);
        grid.setColumnOrder(columns);

        add(grid);
    }

    private void renderHeader() {
        Label label = new Label("Список пользователей");
        add(label);
    }
}
```

Диалог выглядит так:

```
@UIScope
@SpringComponent
public class AddUserDialog extends Dialog implements KeyNotifier {

    private final UserService userService;

    public AddUserDialog(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();

        Binder<UserDto> binder = new Binder<>();

        TextField username = new TextField();
        PasswordField password = new PasswordField();
        EmailField email = new EmailField();
        TextField phone = new TextField();

        Button saveButton = new Button("Сохранить", VaadinIcon.CHECK.create());
        saveButton.addClickListener(event -> save(binder));

        username.setLabel("Логин");
        password.setLabel("Пароль");
        email.setLabel("E-mail");
        phone.setLabel("Телефон");

        binder.bind(username, UserDto::getUsername, UserDto::setUsername);
        binder.bind(password, UserDto::getPassword, UserDto::setPassword);
        binder.bind(email, UserDto::getEmail, UserDto::setEmail);
        binder.bind(phone, UserDto::getPhone, UserDto::setPhone);

        layout.add(username, password, email, phone, saveButton);
        add(layout);
    }

    private void save(Binder<UserDto> binder) {
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        try {
            binder.writeBean(userDto);
        } catch (ValidationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        userService.save(userDto);
        this.close();
    }
}
```

Подскажите, как мне обновить Grid при закрытии диалога?

Comment: Я в диалог прокидываю callback, который вызывается внутри на кнопке "сохранить" и снаружи уже делает grid.datavoew.refreshAll

Answer (score 0):

Возможно как-кто так...
Но это не точно)

```
    this.addUserDialog.addDialogCloseActionListener((event)->{
        grid.setItems(userService.getAll());
    });
```

Просто добавляете обработчик события закрытия диалогового окна, в котором проставляете свежеполученный список элементов.